# Ruby: Handling different JSON response that is not what is expected

Tags: json, ruby

Searched online and read through the documents, but have not been able to find an answer.  I am fairly new and part of learning Ruby I wanted to make the script below.

The Script essentially does a Carrier Lookup on a list of numbers that are provided through a CSV file.  The CSV file has just one row with the column header "number".

Everything runs fine UNTIL the API gives me an output that is different from the others.  In this example, it tells me that one of the numbers in my file is not a valid US number.  This then causes my script to stop running.

I am looking to see if there is a way to either ignore it (I read about Begin and End, but was not able to get it to work) or ideally either create a separate file with those errors or just put the data into the main file.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

**Ruby Code:**

```
require 'csv'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'


number = 0


CSV.foreach('data1.csv',headers: true) do |row|
    number = row['number'].to_i
    uri = URI("https://api.message360.com/api/v3/carrier/lookup.json?PhoneNumber=#{number}")
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    req.basic_auth 'XXX' , 'XXX'
    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) {|http|
    http.request(req)
    }
    json = JSON.parse(res.body)
    new = json["Message360"]["Carrier"].values


    CSV.open("new.csv", "ab") do |csv|
        csv << new
    end
end
```

**File Data:**

```
number
5556667777
9998887777
```

Good Response example in JSON:

```
{"Message360"=>{"ResponseStatus"=>1, "Carrier"=>{"ApiVersion"=>"3", "CarrierSid"=>"XXX", "AccountSid"=>"XXX", "PhoneNumber"=>"+19495554444", "Network"=>"Cellco Partnership dba Verizon Wireless - CA", "Wireless"=>"true", "ZipCode"=>"92604", "City"=>"Irvine", "Price"=>0.0003, "Status"=>"success", "DateCreated"=>"2018-05-15 23:05:15"}}}
```

**The response that causes Script to stop:**

```
{
    "Message360": {
        "ResponseStatus": 0,
        "Errors": {
            "Error": [
                {
                    "Code": "ER-M360-CAR-111",
                    "Message": "Allowed Only Valid E164 North American Numbers.",
                    "MoreInfo": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you can just check `json["Message360"]["ResponseStatus"]` first for a 0 or 1 to indicate failure or success.

I'd probably add a `rescue` to help catch any other errors (malformed JSON, network issue, etc.)

```
CSV.foreach('data1.csv',headers: true) do |row|
    number = row['number'].to_i
...
    json = JSON.parse(res.body)
    if json["Message360"]["ResponseStatus"] == 1  
        new = json["Message360"]["Carrier"].values

        CSV.open("new.csv", "ab") do |csv|
            csv << new
        end
    else
        # handle bad response
    end
rescue StandardError => e
    # request failed for some reason, log e and the number?
end
```